# How to store json file in scrapy?

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am currently using Scrapy to crawl some domains from different website and I wonder how to save my data in a local json file with the format of either a list or a dictionary with the key of 'domain' and a list of domains as value.

In the crawler file, the item is like this:

```py
item['domain'] = 'xxx'.extract()
yield item

import json
import codecs

class ChinazPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.file = codecs.open('save.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8')

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        line = json.dumps(dict(item), ensure_ascii=False) + "\n"
        self.file.write(line)
        return item
```

What I expect is:

```py
{"domain": "['google.com', 'cnn.com', 'yahoo.com']"}
```

or just simply save all domains that I crawled as a list in json, either way works for me.

Answer (score 5):

It's rather simple. Json is default scrapy exporter.
You can use it by turning on output to JSON file:

```
scrapy runspider yourspider.py -o filename.json
```

Scrapy will automatically determine format you with to have by file type.
Other options are `.csv` and `.jsonline`.

It's an easy way. Otherwize you can write your own `ItemExporter`. Take a look at [exporters documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html).

NB:

You don't even need to open file during spider initiation, scrapy will manage it by itself.
Just yield items and scrapy will write it to file automatically.

---

Scrapy is most suitable for `one page -> one item` schema.
What you want is scrape all items in advance and then export them as single list.

So you should have some variable like `self.results`, append there new domains from every `process_item()` call. And then export it on spider close event.
There's shortcut for this signal. So you can just add:

```
def closed(self, reason):
    # write self.results list to JSON file.
```

[More documentation on Spider.closed() method](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=closed#scrapy.spiders.Spider.closed).

Comment: I tried this way, but I got something like this{"domain": ["www.cebbank.com"]}
{"domain": ["www.xiaojukeji.com"]}
{"domain": ["www.360.cn"]}, but I expect that everything in the same dict like this{"domain": "['google.com', 'cnn.com', 'yahoo.com']"}, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you can append to list/set of domains inside just one item and then yield it once. Also, maybe this link will be helpful: https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-jsonschema

Comment: updated an answer since it was too much for a comment.